# Classic ASP Variable comparison issue

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I've inherited a very large Classic ASP site that has recently had an error discovered. It reads and writes from an Access database multiple times, and all of that is working as intended. However, I believe there is an error in this part of the code:

```
Dim SeptAvg, mvUPreq, mvSeptAvg

SeptAvg = CDbl(rs.fields(5))
mvUPreq = -0.15

        if SeptAvg <= mvUPreq then 
            mvSeptAvg = true 
         else 
            mvSeptAvg = false 
         end if
```

Now in this case, the `SeptAvg` in the access database is -8.5%. This expression should be evaluating to True - but it's not. Immediately after this code, there is an update to the Access database that sets the field (which is a checkbox in the Access database) to true or false. The checkbox is always left unchecked. I have checked and rechecked the database update code and I know there are no errors there. Is there something happening with the CDbl on the -8.5% value from the database?

Please advise, because I have very limited Classic ASP experience.

Comment: Do Response.Write("septavg: " + SeptAvg)  let us know what it says right there and you we can debug.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo when I made the post - I've corrected it. The -8.5% value is stored in an Access table (.mdb) and the Data Type for that field/column is Number

Comment: @Prospector That is one of my main problems - debugging this thing. I've tried the Response.Write and a few other things (including hosting the site on local IIS and trying to debug ASP through Visual Studio), but I can't get any of it to work. The Response.Write isn't showing up anything because after the form is submitted it gets redirected several times

Comment: @HansUp There is definitely no Option Explicit defined in the code. This code is roughly 13,000 lines long in a single .asp document - a very unorganized nightmare. Instead of putting Option Explicit at the top of the page, could I just set an initial boolean value to mvUpreq?

Comment: You can use a JS Alert with SeptAvg. You can temporarily use Session["test"] = SptAvg; and get the value from any page it redirects to.

Comment: @HansUp, uninitialized variables are set to [`Empty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8tbc79x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), not `Null` (and yes, it does make a difference, due to the fact that VBScript [implicitly converts `Empty` to 0 when comparing to a number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-8.5% = -0.085` and `-0.085` is indeed larger than `-0.15`.  This is why it is evaluating to `true`

```
-1 > -10
Abs(1) < Abs(10)
1 < 10
```

Answer (score 1):

-8.5% expressed as a decimal is -0.085

So the `If` condition is equivalent to ...

```
if -0.085 <= -0.15 then
```

But -0.085 is greater than -0.15, so the condition is not `True`, so `mvSeptAvg` does not get set to `True`.

Comment: I  think it remained False. See a shareef's answer and my comment below. Thanks for your help HansUp

Comment: @HansUp, uninitialized variables are set to [`Empty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8tbc79x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), not `Null`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it evaluated as `TRUE`, you need to tweak your code a little bit :

```
Dim SeptAvg, mvUPreq, mvSeptAvg  

SeptAvg = CDbl(rs.fields(5))
mvUPreq = -0.15

if abs(SeptAvg) <= abs(mvUPreq) then 
   mvSeptAvg = true 
else 
   mvSeptAvg = false 
end if
```